Android application doesn't save data on firebase firestore console site
I tried putting firestore using the option in Android Studio which is in "Tools" and I also tried putting it directly (putting the dependencies and everything else). Also I connected my project on the firebase console and I checked it and it is connected, but when I run the app and try to save data from the app, nothing shows on the firebase console website.
package com.example.finalonaloto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private EditText enterTitle;
    private EditText enterThought;
    private Button saveButton;

    // Klucoj
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_THOUGHT = "thought";

    // Praenje konekcija so Firestore
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;


        });
        Log.d(TAG, "Firestore instance: " + db);

        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        enterTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        enterThought = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_thoughts);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String title = enterTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                String thought = enterThought.getText().toString().trim();

                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                data.put(KEY_THOUGHT, thought);

                db.collection("Journal")
                        .document("First Thoughts")
                        .set(data)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to save data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + task.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to cpom[lete data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}

Putting firestore using the option in Android Studio which is in "Tools" and I also tried putting it directly (putting the dependencies and everything else). Also I connected my project on the firebase console and I checked it and it is connected. The toast message doesn't appear and collection is not created, data not saved. Also, logcat shows no error at all.

Is any of the Toast messages shown?

@AlexMamo no, none at all

onClick is triggered?
